# SQL Multi valued table search query curiosity

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to make an SQL database that has information about civilians like table `men` has the following rows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[men](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] GO

INSERT INTO [men] VALUES
    (1, 'Cheif01'),
    (2, 'Player01'),
    (3, 'Artist02'),
    (4, 'Artist03');

SELECT * FROM [men];
```

Result:
[image for men table rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9i4F.png)

and another table `men_attr` to specify some attributes about men and has the following rows:

it is clear that each row in the men table has different unique attributes so I made a separate table for attributes.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[men_attr](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [man] [int] NULL,
    [attr] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [value] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] GO

INSERT INTO [men_attr] VALUES
    (1, 1, 'galarriesNo', '2'),
    (2, 1, 'type', 'brush artist'),
    (3, 1, 'restaurant', 'subway'),
    (4, 1, 'fifaNo', '555'),
    (5, 1, 'club', 'FCB'),
    (6, 1, 'galarriesNo', '2'),
    (7, 1, 'galarriesNo', '5');

SELECT * FROM [men_attr];
```

Result:
[image for men_attr table rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3thTp.png)

Now, I need to select all men by a dynamic multi attributes variable like

```
declare @attrs XML = '<r>
    <attr>
        <name>galarriesNo</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </attr>
    <attr>
        <name>club</name>
        <value>FCB</value>
    </attr>
</r>';
```

**My Questions:**

1. Is my dataset is correct or you can advise me another set (ERD)?
2. How can I get the following query dynamically based on the @attr variable?

```
SELECT * FROM [men] WHERE (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM men_attr WHERE men_attr.man = men.id AND (
    -- WHILE LOOP OTHER OR ANY METHOD START
        -- EACH LINE OF THESE ARE GENERATED DYNAMICALLY 
        ([attr] = 'galarriesNo' AND [value] = '2')
        OR
        ([attr] = 'club' AND [value] = 'FCB')
    -- WHILE LOOP OTHER OR ANY METHOD ENDS
    )
) <= 1
```

to get the result:

```
id          name
--         -------
1           Artist01
3           Player01
4           Artist02
```

My previous code will work but it is generated by a static code I need to get attr and values **DYNAMICALLY**.

My SQL server `version` is

```
SELECT @@VERSION;
------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: I did as what you @YitzhakKhabinsky advised thank you, I'm waiting for geeks to answer me.